# Same sRGB image different colors in Lightroom, Windows, Web and Android

Tags: color, color-management, color-spaces, icc-profile

recently I've started having troubles with my image colors. The same image (sRGB) looks different in Lightroom, Windows, and Android.

I import my photos that were shot on Fujifilm X-T3 in raw (.RAF) to Lightroom, edit them, then export them to JPG (sRGB).

When I open the image on Windows it looks different (and ugly) than in Lightroom (it was Soft Proofed for sRGB). If I open the image in Photoshop it looks as it should (RGB in Photoshop is set to sRGB IEC61966-2.1.). And if I open the image on my Android 8 phone it looks also as it should.

I even tried Converting to sRGB profile in Photoshop. It looks the same in Photoshop, but on Windows, it's again different.

I'm kinda confused, but thanks in advance for your help!

[image: After upload it looks ugly]

EDIT: On desktop Chrome, the image looks ugly, but on my phone, it looks as it should

EDIT 2: On my notebook, the image looks fine, so I guess it's something with my Windows 10, but in Color Management settings everything looks fine.

[image]

Comment: Are your devices all actually hardware calibrated? Throwing a generic profile at a device only works if it's correctly calibrated in the first place.

Comment: No, I don't have my monitor hardware calibrated. 

But I supposed that when the image displays correctly in Photoshop (while using sRGB IEC61966-2.1. profile) it also should display correctly in Windows (Chrome, Photo viewer) which is also using sRGB IEC61966-2.1.

 It looks like a software problem to me (maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: You are describing several different devices and software. It's not clear what device is using what software. For instance, when you say "Photoshop" is that on the same physical device as "Windows"? What about "Web"? "Lightroom"? Could you clarify your question by including a list of devices along with what software they are running?

Comment: Have you tried disabling Windows color management entirely to see what happens?

Comment: I'm so sorry. It was even confusing for me.

Comment: Basically, I had an issue on only one physical device (let's call it "PC1"). On my PC1 I exported a photo from Lightroom to sRGB photo. When I opened this photo on Windows Photo viewer (on PC1) it had completely different colors and exposure than in Lightroom. When I opened the exact same photo in Photoshop (on PC1) it had the same colors and exposure as in Lightroom. Photoshop colors were set to sRGB IEC61966-2.1. profile. When I viewed the photo through Chrome (on PC1) the colors were again different than they should be.

Comment: What helped me was turning off the color management. So thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see here the device used to compare color to judge it's accuracy is not a calibrated or profiled device.  Just using a canned profile for a display says nothing about the actual viewing conditions or the displays characterization, so that is a broken section of the color-managed workflow.   Color appearance on a phone (depending on the type is) is also variable due to a function of human vision called adaption.  This results in humans being able to perceive a "white" under any light source without issue but displays are static. Their white points don't change with their environment.  The new iPhone OS attempts to adjust for ambient light color temperature but sadly does a poor job.  Displays, on the other hand, are static, so their white point can be changed in a profile or on some better high-end products with hardware controls, but those displays must be in a static environment without the variability of window light which we all know goes from cool in the morning to warm in the evening.

Also when comparing use a colorimetric intent instead of perceptual rendering

Then we come to the real issue of color management systems.  Windows uses WCS, which is based on CIECam02 which was proven to have some major flaws in the way it performs color transforms.  Phone OS's will have their one color systems which may or may not be a subset of the larger platforms CMS.

So Comparing color in this way is fraught with variables, that if not managed properly will not provide a visual match.

Answer (score 0):

Each device has it's own adjustments on top of the baseline.   Each device is tweaked differently and each device has a different video card and screen charcteristics.  They will never completely match each other.  You can adjust each one for the best possible image but that is your only option if they are all set properly for srgb profile.

Comment: I mean the colors and exposure were totally different in Lightroom/Photoshop and Windows Photo Viewer. I know, I wrote it in a very confusing style, but I was frustrated AF. But thank you for your time anyway.